# Clearing Regex cache in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am using the Regex method `Regex.Replace` for large strings. Since these strings are cached, it is consuming a lot of memory.

I want to clear these Regex cache once a particulate operation is completed, so that the strings are garbage collected.

I can set the Regex cache size using `Regex.CacheSize` property, but how can I keep the cache size and clear the cache? Setting the cache size to zero will impact performance since I'm using this method multiple times for the same strings.

If I set the cache size to zero and reset it back to the old value, will the cached objects be discarded and garbage collected?

Code:

```
// languageDetails is a xml string holding, xml comments, name space etc. 
// Need to remove the comments.

string pattern = "(<!--.*?-->)";

string languageDetails = Regex.Replace(
  languageDetails, 
  pattern, 
  string.Empty, 
  RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Please share code snippet.

Comment: The Regex declaration and usage is important for your question

Comment: If your data is XML, don't use regex - parse it instead (e.g. with `XmlDocument`).

Answer (score 0):

Look at thesource code:

```
public static int CacheSize
{
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] get
    {
        return Regex.cacheSize;
    }

    [__DynamicallyInvokable] set
    {
        if (value < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof (value));
        Regex.cacheSize = value;
        if (Regex.livecode.Count <= Regex.cacheSize)
            return;
        lock (Regex.livecode)
        {
            while (Regex.livecode.Count > Regex.cacheSize)
                Regex.livecode.RemoveLast();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, setting the value to 0 will call `Regex.livecode.RemoveLast();`

So, it will clean the `livecode` list.

Answer (score 0):

> ... for large strings. Since these strings are cached , it is consuming a lot of memory.

The input/output strings are not cached in any way.

The cache stores compiled regular expressions. So unless you have very many very large patterns, your memory problem is not caused by the cache.

Comment: Thanks , Yes, Input /Output strings are not cached, but still they are referenced by RegEX and will not be garbage collected. I tested code with resetting the RegEx cache size, and these references are released.

Comment: I doubt that very (very) much. If the Regex could do that it would be a bug. Can you write and post a small demonstration?